# Can I wrap up 'Power Automate flow' into a file?

Tags: automation, bots, power-automate, rpa

I want to create a 'Power Automate flow' and wrap it up into a file so I can execute the automation by simple calling that file. Is that possible ?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by “simply calling that file”? It’s a cloud service, not an executable file.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly like running a file. But you can trigger flows by using a hyperlink from the When an HTTP request is received
https://manueltgomes.com/reference/power-automate-trigger-reference/when-an-http-request-is-received-trigger/

That might be an option. It is a premium action though.